# Show that there is a compact neighbourhood $B$ of $x$ such that $B \cap F = \emptyset$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space, $F \subset X$ closed and $x \notin F$ . Show that there is a compact neighbourhood $B$ of $x$ such that $B \cap F = \emptyset$.

I'm trying to use the fact that compact subspaces of Hausdorff spaces are closed

this is not homework, it is from a book with no solutions

Comment: Is it compact *metric* space or just compact Hausdorff space? If the latter than the [metric-spaces] tag should be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$F$ is compact, because it is closed in the compact space $X$ (so we are using the general fact that "closed in compact is compact").

For every $y \in F$, we pick disjoint open sets $U_y$ (contains $y$) and $V_y$ (contains $x$) by Hausdorffness (here we use $x \notin F$, so that all these pairs consist of 2 points!).

Finitely many $U_y$, say $U_{y_1},\ldots,U_{y_k}$ cover $F$, by compactness. 
Then we can take $V = \overline{V_{y_1} \cap \ldots \cap V_{y_k} }$ which is a neighbourhood of $y$ (as it contains a finite intersection of neighbourhoods). And for every point $p$ in $F$ we know it is in some $U_{y_i}$, which is disjoint from $V_{y_i}$. So $V_{y_1} \cap\ldots\cap V_{y_k} \subset V_{y_i} \subset X \setminus U_{y_i}$ and as the last set is closed, $V \subset X\setminus U_{y_i}$ which means that $p \notin V$. As $p$ is arbitrary in $F$, $F$ is disjoint from $V$, as required.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Compact Hausdorff space is completely regular, so you can separate $x$ from $F$ by disjoint open neighborhoods, $U,V$ such that $x\in U$ and $F\subseteq V$. Show that the closure of $U$ is compact and disjoint of $F$.

Comment: I was going to go with completely regular. :-)

Comment: @Arthur: Yeah, that's what I said! :-)

Comment: Having two kids must be destroying my literacy; this is the second time today I've misread stuff like this.

Comment: @Arthur: Oh, I'm pulling your legs there buddy. I used the five minutes window to pretend that I did. :-) Muahahah! :-D

Comment: Hooray for my (approximate) sanity!!!!